# How to alert user when a specific word is typed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript and I'm creating my first Chrome extention. It's really just a personal challenge.

I want to alert the user when they type certain words on any website. Perhaps a search input field on Google or Bing, or maybe when they're typing a Facebook status.

I am not very familiar with Javascript, so is this possible? After trail and error, I came up with this, but it only works on a specific input field on a website.

```
$(function() {
    var triggerWords = ['badword', 'wordbad'];
    $('#input').keyup(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
            if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == triggerWords[i]) {
                alert('Alert! You've typed a blocked word.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Then why don't you target all elements where text can be inputted? For example input, textarea, contenteditable divs, etc

Comment: How would I do that? Like this maybe `('input', 'textarea')`

Comment: Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/wonpmquw/

Comment: You answered my question. How can I close this?

Comment: i suggest use input for copy paste

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wonpmquw/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers above work well for a single input. However you might have to change your function a little if you want it to work for dynamically generated inputs as well.

**This doesn't work on dynamically generated inputs** ([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wonpmquw/3/))

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(triggerWords[i]) != -1) {
            alert("Alert! You've typed a blocked word.");
        }
    }
});
```

**But this does** ([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wonpmquw/4/))

```
 $(document).on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(triggerWords[i]) != -1) {
            alert("Alert! You've typed a blocked word.");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Good approach, you're on the right way.

`$(function() {` add an anonymous function but you have to call it by hand (and its difficult to call a function without a name :) ). Better use this: `$( document ).ready(function() {` It told the document to call this anonymous function when the document is ready.

`$('#input')` selects all elements with the `ìd` == `#input`. This isn't what you want. You would like to select all `input` elements (remove the id-selector `#`). BTW: `.someClass` will select all elements with `class` == `someClass`.

`$(this).val().toLowerCase() == triggerWords[i]` test if **only** one of the blocked words is typed. It's totally ok, but I think you'd prefer if the typed `string` **contains** one of the words. Use `$(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(triggerWords[i]) != -1`

Sum all together:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var triggerWords = ['badword', 'wordbad'];
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
            if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(triggerWords[i]) != -1) {
                alert("Alert! You've typed a blocked word.");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

One last thing, you can use the JS version of for-each like this:

```
for(var word in triggerWords){
  if($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1) {...}
}
```

Comment: `$(function() {` is equivalent to `$( document ).ready(function() {`. It is just a shortcut